# Solving functional equations clarification

Tags: functional-equations

[image]

how exactly did he apply 1.39 to get

$$f(x-1)^2 =f(1-x)^2$$

Comment: From the book [Functional equations and how to solve them](https://www.isinj.com/mt-usamo/Functional%20Equations%20and%20How%20To%20Solve%20Them%20-%20Christopher%20G.%20Small.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

It is not difficult; note that
$$
f(x-1)^2=f((x-1)^2)=f((1-x)^2)=f(1-x)^2.$$